# Is there a way to make my discord bot differentiate between successful and unsuccessful commands for another discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a reminder bot for **EPICRPG** and other bots, but if for example, I type *RPG Hunt*, it will start a timer, be it successful or not. Successful means used the cd, unsuccessful means the
hunt was still on cd or the bot didn't accept the command(spam or in event).

1. I tried having my bot detect the message that starts with *RPG hunt*, but it will detect unsuccessful commands too.
2. Then I tried having the bot detect the reply/messages of **EPICRPG**, so like
   **user**: rpg hunt
   **EPICRPG**: user found and killed...
   I tried having the bot detect messages that includes *"found and killed"* sent by **EPICRPG**. But there is more than 1 message by **EPICRPG** that includes *"found and killed"*.
   3.Then next I wanted to try having the bot detect message that starts with `RPG hunt` and any reply that includes *"found and killed"*, so basically a command that detects 2 authors in 2 messages, but someone told me that can't happen so I didn't even try to code that.
   I'm using discord.js

1st try code :

```
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('rpg hunt')) {  
                  client.command.get('hunt').execute(message, args);
}
```

2nd try code :

```
 if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('found and killed')) {
    if (message.content.author.id('<@555955826880413696>').toLowerCase().includes('found and killed')) {
            client.command.get('hunt').execute(message, args);
}
}
```

hunt.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'hunt',
    description: 'Reminds for hunt commands.',
    execute(message, args) {
    setTimeout(function(){
                    message.channel.send(`Time to Hunt, ${message.author}!`);
                }, 60000); 
}
}
```